# Find what from svchost is using port

Tags: windows, powershell

I followed another answer to find the process that uses port 8000 when I start my computer.

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 8000).OwningProcess
```

That shows that `svchost` is using the port.  So I kill it with no issue and run what I want to run on port 8000.

But is there a way to see what from `svchost` is using that port, so that I can prevent it from starting up?

Comment: There are many Windows svchost processes legitimately running - why are you trying to stop them?

Comment: @John I'm just trying to stop whatever is using port 8000.

Comment: Perhaps this Microsoft post will help  ...  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/what-port-is-that-service-using/ba-p/373292   or get TCP View from Nirsoft and try that.

Comment: Rather than disabling/kill it, might it worth be trying to reserve the ephemeral port such that the process that is taking it uses something else if possible, e.g. `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=8000 numberofports=1`

Comment: `$port = 8000;
$pFullName = ((Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort $port).OwningProcess) | Select Path).Path | % {If($_){$_}};
$pName = $pFullName | % { $_.Split("\")[-1] };
$pName | %{ Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$_'" | Select CommandLine | FL };`

Answer (score 2):

By default, each `svchost` instance hosts (or used to host) multiple services. You can read about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/svchost-service-refactoring). You cannot properly determine which service is responsible for process activity this way. You can still see which services are hosted in the process in question, using PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "ProcessId='$PID'"
```

for example:

```
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "ProcessId='1448'"

ExitCode  : 0
Name      : EFS
ProcessId : 1448
StartMode : Manual
State     : Running
Status    : OK

ExitCode  : 0
Name      : KeyIso
ProcessId : 1448
StartMode : Manual
State     : Running
Status    : OK

ExitCode  : 0
Name      : SamSs
ProcessId : 1448
StartMode : Auto
State     : Running
Status    : OK

ExitCode  : 0
Name      : VaultSvc
ProcessId : 1448
StartMode : Manual
State     : Running
Status    : OK
```

(These are not hosted in `svchost`, but you get the idea.) **You cannot always tell which services they are from the process’ command line.** You must use the services API for this.

You can disable this multi-hosting per service, using `sc` (with *wuauserv*, the Windows Update service):

```
sc config wuauserv type= own
```

You can then check again and see which service exactly is responsible.

You can switch back again, too:

```
sc config wuauserv type= share
```

Comment: Current Windows versions automatically disable multi-hosting if there's at least of 8 GB of memory; MS had an article about this change and a registry key to force individual hosting globally but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The `svchost` process is used to run system services.
It would be better to figure out which system service is using this port,
then disable it permanently (if it's not useful).

You can find that by looking at the command-line of the `svchost.exe`
process. The `-k` parameter identifies the system service.

You have already figured out how to get the process-id that uses the port.
To get the command-line, run PowerShell as Administrator and enter
the following command (example for process 4680):

```
gcim win32_process | Where-Object {$_.processid -eq 4680} | select commandline
```

A useful GUI utility is
[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).